# Oracle - Getting the latest list price from list table and append it another product table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list price table, where product prices keeps on changing and another table Product table , which has the entry of dates when the product was sold and at what price. 
I want to compare the price of the product on or before that date ( when it was sold) and put that list price in my product table along with the selling price.

Table like :

```
list price , Valid from ,valid to product  
23  , jul 7 , july 15, X   
24 , jul 20 , july 30,X   
25 , aug 5 , aug 30,X   
20,sep 5,sep 26,X
```

Product  table :

```
Product , Selling price , As of date  
X , 24 , jul 10  
X,39, jul 30  
x,40, aug 28
```

I wish to append a column(ListPrice) to my Product table using the closest dates
to AS_OF_DATE column and List price on that date in Price Table.

```
select Product.*, price.list_price from 
(select '2017-07-20 12:00:00'::timestamp as 
valid_from,select '2017-07-20 12:00:00'::timestamp as valid_from) price  
left join (select '2017-07-20 12:15:00'::timestamp as ts, true as val 
)product on product.ts >= price.valid_from and b.ts < price.valid_to;
```

Please suggest the way to to do it in oracle.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off storing the price that was decided by the business?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `join`

```
select p.*, lp.*
from products p left join
     listprices lp
     on p.product = lp.product and
        p.asofdate >= lp.validfrom and
        p.asofdate <= lp.validto;
```

If you don't want to take the `validto` dates into account . . .

```
select p.*,
       (select max(lp.price) keep (dense_rank first order by lp.validfrom desc)
        from listprices lp
        where p.product = lp.product and
              p.asofdate >= lp.validfrom
      ) as listprice
from products p ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , But strangely i am having way more than records what i have in my left table, however , i just want records equals to that of my left table.

Comment: One more thing, why you are using , max(lp.price) , i want the recent record price which is closest to the date , not the max(price) , could you please explain.

Comment: @LoveTyagi . . . That is the syntax for `keep`.  If the `order by` has unique keys, then you don't have to worry about it.  If you want only one price, then use the second version.  Your list prices table may have overlaps in time.